# How to convert Byte to String?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I need to convert my `Byte` to a `String` because

```
- (NSInteger)write:(const uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)
```

takes a `String` as its first parameter.

What I want:

```
func sendMessage(message: Byte) -> Int {
    return outputStream!.write(message, maxLength: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to provide string, but `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`. Just prepend `message` with `&`:

```
return outputStream!.write(&message, maxLength: 1)
```

Comment: It is a point in the right direction but the compiler says: 'Byte' is not convertible to '@lvalue inout $T5'

Comment: Its because function parameters `msg` is constant (`let`). And `write` function could change `msg` as it is `inout` parameter. Change parameter to variable `func SendMsg(var msg: Byte) -> Int`.

Comment: This could also work: `outputStream!.write([msg], maxLength: 1)` (without the need to make the parameter variable). See "Constant Pointers" in ["Interacting with C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var char = 97

let str = NSString(bytes: &char, length: 1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `UnicodeScalar` to a `String` as such:

```
let theString = String(UnicodeScalar(theByte))
```

Or you can do it one `Character` at a time:

```
let theChar = Character(UnicodeScalar(theByte))
```

Answer (score 0):

For others who came here for the answer to the question:
"How do I convert an `Array` of bytes into a Swift `String`" :

```
String(bytes: byteArray, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

which returns a `String?` (`Optional<String>`).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `NSOutputStream`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutputStream/write:maxLength:) actually shows what @Kirsteins suggested, when looking at the Swift version of the method:

```
func write(_ buffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, maxLength length: Int) -> Int
```