# Passing data from external python script in django to swift

Tags: ios, swift, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to create a swift request where an external python script is run in Django and returns data to the user.

I just cant wrap my head around on what best practices there are or on how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Python script returns**

```
 print(output)
```

**Django views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    inp = request.FILES.get('image').name
    out = run([sys.executable,"//Users//macbookpro//TestAPI//venv//Test_Script.py",inp],
        shell=False,stdout=PIPE, text= True)

    print(out.stdout)

    return Response ({"output": str(out)})
```

**Swift**

```
    to: REST_UPLOAD_API_URL,
    headers: headers,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
                print(stdout)
```

What would be the best way to pass data from the Python script and back to the user? Do i need to create a JSON response in Django and afterwards Decode it in Swift? If so, how would that work? If not, then how can you decode the "stdout" response in Swift which I'm currently receiving.

**Results so far:**

this gives me the desired text response within Django

```
print(out.stdout)
```

In Swift the DebugPrint works but not print:

```
DebugPrint(response) // stdout='MyDesiredText\\n'

print(stdout) // 0x000000010a45d1a8
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to convert it from bytes to a string. Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216200/how-to-convert-byte-to-string) and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry I can't offer more help.  You probably know more about swift than I do so I don't want to give a wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look and see if i can solve it.